# How to fix CustomRepositoryCannotInheritRepositoryError on nestjs app?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Havin problem to run `nestjs` app.

Current ecosystem:
 - Windows 10
 - `node` ver: `v12.10.0`
 - `npm` ver: `6.10.3`
 - `nestjs` ver: `6.14.2`

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/gandra/nestjs-task-managament
cd nestjs-task-managament
npm i
npm run start
```

Receiving following error:

```
CustomRepositoryCannotInheritRepositoryError: Custom entity repository TaskRepository  cannot inherit Repository class without entity being set in the @EntityRepository decorator.
    at new CustomRepositoryCannotInheritRepositoryError (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\typeorm\error\CustomRepositoryCannotInheritRepositoryError.js:10:28)
    at EntityManager.getCustomRepository (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\EntityManager.js:607:23)
    at Connection.getCustomRepository (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:365:29)
    at getCustomRepository (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm.providers.js:15:68)
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm.providers.js:20:24)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:291:55)
    at callback (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:75:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:116:24)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (C:\learn\node\nestjs-task-managament\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:79:9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that following 2 things fixed issue. 
First I have changed `TaskRepository` annotation from `@EntityRepository()` to `@EntityRepository(Task)`. After that fix I have got error `EntityMetadataNotFound`.
Then I have changed `TypeOrm entities` con in file `src/config/typeorm.config.ts` and replaced `entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts'],` with `entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],`.

Answer (score 0):

My case was to take care of two things:

- All `@EntityRepository(hasItsClassHere)`
- Remove circular dependency between the model and the repository.